# Printing prime numbers by calling a function

Tags: c++, function

How to make a function that calls the next prime number every time I call it?

Here's what I've got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void prime();

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    void prime();
}

bool isPrime(int integer)
{
    int x;
    int br = 0;

    for (x = 1; x < integer; x++) {
        if (integer % x == 0) {
            br++;
        }
    }

    if (br == 1) {
        cout << " The number " << integer << " is prime " << endl;
    }
    else if (br > 1) {
        cout << " The number " << integer << " is not prime " << endl;
    }
}

void prime(){
for (int x = 2;x<1000;x++){
    isPrime(x);
}

}
```

Nothing is displayed when I run it.
Edit: Here I added the main function...

Comment: What did you see when you ran it through your debugger?

Comment: Nothing was displayed.

Comment: Edit your code and question to use a `main` function.

Comment: The code that you pasted doesn't even compile. What is `x` in `prime()`?

Comment: @RandomJoe Your debugger displayed absolutely nothing?! Then you have bigger problems.

Comment: This code doesn't compile

Comment: @RandomJoe Thanks for the edit, but your code still doesn't compile. I repeat my question: what is `x` in `prime ()`?

Comment: What do you think `const void` should do?

Comment: All `main` does is declare a function, so not much will happen if you run it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> int main()
> {
>     void prime();
> }
> ```

`void prime();` is a function declaration. It has no effect; the function is not called. You must **call** the function:

```
int main()
{
    prime();
}
```

And then there's another big problem. Your `isPrime` function **doesn't return anything**. Add a `return` statement to it:

```
return br == 1;
```

If you do *not* intend for the function to return anything (and your code currently doesn't use the returned value, so this may indeed be your intention), then make it a `void` function.

Comment: It started printing some numbers (from 700 to 999), but what i want to do is print only 1 prime number and after i call the function again i want to call the next one, but I can't figure it out still :/

Comment: @RandomJoe: If you make the two suggested changes and do not change anything else, then the program *must* work. Otherwise, you have a new problem, possibly worth a new question.

Answer (score 0):

isPrime is boolean function is expecting to return true or false, there is no return in your code. Make it a void if you just want to "cout" the number on the console.

Comment: Changing the bool to void will not make the output appears

Answer (score -1):

The main issue with your code is that you are not returning anything from your `isPrime` function (which should give back a boolean value).

For that you can rewrite your code as:

```
bool is_prime(int integer) {
    if (integer < 2) return true;
    auto range = boost::irange(2, integer);
    auto pred = [integer](auto i) { return integer % i == 0; };
    return find_if(range, pred) == std::end(range);
}
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f1a95c67c174f807)

Second, your main:

```
int main()
{
    void prime();
}
```

Is really just declaring the function `prime`. In order to call it you can write:

```
void prime();
int main() {
    prime();
}
```

Comment: I'd say the main issue is the fact that `main` only contains a function declaration and not a function call... :)

Comment: @ChristianHackl Actually the fact that a function that should return something is not returning anything is UB. I'd wage that UB is worse than a `main` that does nothing.

Comment: @Jeffrey: Well, I don't dispute the importance of the `return` statement, of course. Though I wonder if it's also UB if no caller uses the return value. To be honest, I couldn't tell without checking the standard or doing some research.

Comment: And I wonder why this is being downvoted... It looks like a nice modern alternative, though I wonder why you don't use `std::find_if`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Why would I prefer it to `boost::find_if`?

Comment: @Jeffrey: Because it's standard and `boost::find_if` is not.

Comment: @ChristianHackl So? This solution is using Boost.Range anyway, and using `std::find_if` costs more in terms of things that can be specified the wrong way (as you have to call `begin` and `end` on the range).